# Is there a way around cross domain publishing if both sides agree?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a site which people can save photos and other things, they save them to a list. These lists are dynamically generated based on content added.

I have been asked by users if they can can 'embed' their list into their blogs and/or other pages.

I know I could use iframes but the issue there is, I cannot set a height because the content is dynamic. If I 'guessed' the height it would almost definitely be wrong based on so many different viewing devices being available.

So, I have the code, the user wants to add it to their page and trusts me, is there now a solution?

I'm using PHP, javascript and JQuery.

Comment: [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 0):

atleast 3 ways

1. Ask your user to insert Iframe code
2. Ask user to create a unique div in their blog. Also, user includes a script tag which gets data from your site and renders at the position of unique div
3. Ask user to initiate a jsonp request. Your server returns back jsonp response. User can then use some/all of this data for his purpose